# Dropping Azure Schema or Deleting Rows takes a very long time

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Vague title I know.

I have, at the moment, 16,000 rows in my database. This was created just while in development, I want to now delete all these rows so I can start again (so I don't have duplicate data).

The database is on SQL Azure.

If I run a select query

```
SELECT [Guid]
  ,[IssueNumber]
  ,[Severity]
  ,[PainIndex]
  ,[Status]
  ,[Month]
  ,[Year]
  ,[DateCreated]
  ,[Region]
  ,[IncidentStart]
  ,[IncidentEnd]
  ,[SRCount]
  ,[AggravatingFactors]
  ,[AggravatingFactorDescription]
  FROM [dbo].[WeeklyGSFEntity]
GO
```

This returns all the rows, and SSMS says this takes 49 seconds.

If I attempt to drop the table, this goes on for 5 minutes plus.

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[WeeklyGSFEntity]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[WeeklyGSFEntity]    Script Date: 10/01/2013 09:46:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeeklyGSFEntity](
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IssueNumber] [int] NULL,
    [Severity] [int] NULL,
    [PainIndex] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Month] [int] NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [Region] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IncidentStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [IncidentEnd] [datetime] NULL,
    [SRCount] [int] NULL,
    [AggravatingFactors] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AggravatingFactorDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Guid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO
```

If I attempt to delete each row, this also takes 5 minutes plus.

```
DELETE
  FROM [dbo].[WeeklyGSFEntity]
GO
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just that this is *big* data and I'm being impatient?

**UPDATE:**

Dropping the entire database took some 25 seconds.

Importing 22,000 rows (roughly the same 16,000 plus more) into `localdb\v11.0` took 6 seconds. I know this is local but surely the local dev server is slower than Azure? Surely...

**UPDATE the second:**

Recreating the database and recreating the schema (with (Fluent) NHibernate), and then inserting some 20,000 rows took 2 minutes 6 seconds. All Unit Tests pass.
Is there anything I can do to look back?

Comment: 16,000 elements in your DB is relatively small and delete should not take that long. Is that the entire SQL script you have? Don't you have any additional scripts creating some triggers? Also what is your database with your data?

Comment: That's just it.
Nothing else, those are the scripts generated by SSMS itself. This is a Web instance on Windows Azure but still,
What do you mean what is my database? It's just text, there are no relationships and it was 16MB according to the Azure Database Manager (although that reported 25,600 rows where as SSMS reported 16,000).

Comment: Seems very strange that a drop would take so long. If you just want it done you could try doing a TRUNCATE first, and then a DROP. But I'd still want to know why the DROP is taking so long in case it's indicative of another problem.

Comment: @BrianReischl it just took 2 minutes to insert the data. Before I never let it complete because it took over 5 minutes... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping and recreating the database sped things up considerably.

The reason for this is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Possible there is an open transaction on causing a lock on the table. This could be caused by cancelling an operation half way like we all do during dev.

Do a `sp_who2` and see which Id is in blkby column. If there is one that's it.

To kill that process do `kill id`

Comment: Of course dropping the database will also kill that lock